# Weird reflections happening in Eevee regardless of render settings (even default)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]Can anyone explain what is happening? Lighting is inconsistent between frames, and random frames have these strange blurry reflections of random objects. It looks like it has a reflective plane in front of the camera, but there is no reflective plane. I have a volume box in the scene for godrays, but I turned that off, and turned off refraction just to see if that would get rid of it, and it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question, as well as a screenshot of your scene in the viewport. As it is, it just looks like you have a reflective plane in front of the camera.

Comment: Added more info. Thoughts?